# Mapping a custom serializable class toa datasource

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

I have the following class:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class CarParts
    {
        public string PartId { get; set; }
        public int PartCost { get; set; }


        public Button Edit{ get; set; }
    }
```

What I would like to do is have:

```
 List<CarParts> parts = new List<CarParts>();
(fill parts)


m_StockParts.Columns.Add()//map column to 'Edit'
m_StockParts.Columns.Add()//map column to 'PartId'
m_StockParts.Columns.Add()//map column to 'PartCost'
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DataSource` like this:

```
     List<CarParts> parts = new List<CarParts>();
     parts.Add(new CarParts(){PartId = "2", PartCost = 233, Edit =new Button(){Text = "btn"}});
     InitializeComponent();
     dataGridView1.DataSource = parts;
```

and then get something like this:

[image]

as for the button column. as far as i know you can't add a button column in DataSource and you'll have to add it manually. you can keep in `CarParts` a method to handle the button instead of the button itself and do:

```
var buttonCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
buttonCol.Name = "ButtonColumnName";
buttonCol.HeaderText = "Edit";
buttonCol.Text = "Edit";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonCol);
```

and go through the buttons, register them to the method of the carParts

Comment: @meds indeed, do you want a button there?

Comment: yes                       



......................................................................